# Why do homotopy orbits commute with the Eilenberg–Mac Lane spectrum functor?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, stable-homotopy

Let $H: \mathsf{sAb}\to H\mathbb{Z}\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ denote the Eilenberg–Mac Lane functor sending a simplicial abelian group $M_\bullet$ to the infinite delooping of its geometric realization, i.e., $HM_\bullet:=B^\infty\lvert M_\bullet\rvert$.

For $G$ a group (for me $G=C_2$), I will write $(-)_ {hG}$ for the homotopy $G$-orbits in both $\mathsf{sMod}_ {\mathbb{Z}[G]}$ and $H\mathbb{Z}[G]\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$. More concretely, $X_ {hG}:= X\wedge_{G}EG_+$ for $X\in H\mathbb{Z}[G]\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ and
$$
(M_\bullet)_ {hG}=\operatorname{Diag}(M_\bullet\otimes_ {\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z}[E_\bullet G]): [p]\longmapsto M_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}\mathbb{Z}[G^{\times(p+1)}], \quad M_\bullet\in \mathsf{sMod}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}.
$$

**Question:** I think it is well-known that there is a natural equivalence of functors
$$
H((-)_ {hG})\simeq (H(-))_ {hG}: \mathsf{sMod}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}\longrightarrow H\mathbb{Z}\text{-}\mathsf{Mod},
$$
but I haven't found any reference for this fact. How should the argument go?

If $H: \mathsf{sAb}\to H\mathbb{Z}\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ was a left Quillen functor (for appropriate model structures in the domain and codomain) this would be immediate, but I don't know if this is true. I am also aware of Shipley's paper [HZ-algebra spectra are differential graded algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209215) (see Proposition 2.10), but I don't see why the total derived functor $\mathbb{H}$ there should coincide with my $H(-)$ (under the Dold–Kan correspondence).

Comment: Thank you for your excellent TeX, although you might care to use `\operatorname{Diag}` in place of `\mathrm{Diag}` for semantic content, especially if you ever drop parentheses (compare $\operatorname{Diag} M$ `\operatorname{Diag} M` to $\mathrm{Diag} M$ `\mathrm{Diag} M`).  Anyway, I edited that while I was editing to fix a non-mathematical issue, which is that the name is "[Mac Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saunders_Mac_Lane)", not "Maclane".

Comment: @LSpice: The Eilenberg–MacLane spaces predate MacLane's insertion of a space into his last name, and later name changes do not retroactively propagate into existing terminology.  So for this specific concept, the name is typeset without a space (but with a capitalized L).

Comment: The geometric realization functor is a left Quillen functor from simplicial abelian groups to abelian topological monoids.  The functor B^∞ preserves homotopy colimits, and may even be a left Quillen functor with the right choice of models (the question does not state which model for B^∞ is being used).  Combined together, these two facts imply that the Eilenberg–MacLane spectrum construction as it is defined in the question is a homotopy cocontinuous functor.  To say more, one needs to fix a specific model for B^∞ first.